# Why does this dynamic expression fail in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

I am trying to build a dynamic, reusable WHERE clause expression to evaluate two joined objects in Entity Framework.

The following is working correctly in isolation:

```
var result1 = dbContext.Entity1
  .Join(dbContext.Entity2,
    e1 => new {e1.SomeProperty, e1.AnotherProperty},
    e2 => new {e2.SomeProperty, e2.AnotherProperty},
    (e1, e2) => new JoinedEntity1Entity2 {Entity1 = e1, Entity2 = e2})
  .AsQueryable()
  .Where(JoinedEntity1Entity2Filter())
  .Select(entities => new FilteredEntity 
   { 
     a = entities.Entity1.A,
     b = entities.Entity2.B
   })
```

JoinedEntity1Entity2Filter() looks something like this:

```
public Expression<Func<JoinedEntity1Entity2, bool>> JoinedEntity1Entity2Filter()
{
    return joinedEntities =>
      joinedEntities.Entity1.SomeValue == joinedEntities.Entity2.SomeValue;
}
```

However, when I try to use the query above as a sub select of another simple query, it fails and I get an error.

For example:

```
var result2 = from x in dbContext.Entity3
    select new SomeObject 
    {
       // this the query from above
       FilteredEntities = dbContext.Entity1
                            .Join(dbContext.Entity2,
                               e1 => new {e1.SomeProperty, e1.AnotherProperty},
                               e2 => new {e2.SomeProperty, e2.AnotherProperty},
                               (e1, e2) => new JoinedEntity1Entity2 {Entity1 = e1, Entity2 = e2})
                            .AsQueryable()
                            .Where(JoinedEntity1Entity2Filter())
                            .Select(entities => new FilteredEntity 
                             { 
                                 a = entities.Entity1.A,
                                 b = entities.Entity2.B
                             })
    }
```

The error I get is the following:

> Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.

And here is the top of the stack trace:

> at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetLambdaExpression(Expression argument)

Thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide full query where it fails (without "...")?

Comment: You use `.AsQueryable()` in the first code snippet. You should probably use it in the second snippet as well. But that's hard to tell without seeing what precedes the `Where` clause.

Comment: I assume the "..." is the exact query the OP listed at the top.  I would start diagnosing this by commenting out the Where clause or hard coding values in it.  You want to find out what causes this query in a loop to be unhappy.  Also try sticking a .FirstOrDefault after the Select and also a ToList for FilteredEntities.  My guess is that there's something not right about building an expression inside a loop and that's causing EF a hard time creating an execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Sorry, I assumed that "..." would imply that the query was the same as defined in the "working" query.  I've updated the one with the subselect to match the first.

@BradRem I will give your suggestion a shot, and respond shortly.